# How does extern "C" affect linking?

Tags: c++, linker, header-files

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55800896/not-including-the-corresponding-header-h-file-in-the-implementation-cpp-fi), I am able to compile this program without having to include `hello.h` in `hello.cpp`. 
But if I use `extern "C"`, then I get an undefined reference to `hello` in `main.cpp` during linking. Why is that?

hello.hpp:

```
extern "C" void hello();
```

hello.cpp:

```
//#include "hello.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void hello() { 
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
    hello();
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
g++ -c main.cpp hello.cpp
g++ main.o hello.o
main.cpp: undefined reference to 'hello'
```

Comment: I hesitate to say this is an exact [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/22081063) as it doesn't seem to directly answer your specific question, but it might have some useful information for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern "C"` removes the name decoration that most compilers apply to C++ function names.  If you're trying to call an undecorated name but you've only compiled a decorated one, they're not going to find each other.

Comment: With conventional linkers every function (that isn't local to an object file/library) needs to have a unique name. In C all functions have a unique name (no overloading, no class membership, etc), so name decoration isn't necessary (and the compiler can use either no decoration or a fixed decoration scheme, e.g. prepending a `_`). C++ has function overloading (two functions with the same name and distinct argument types) and decoration is needed so the linker sees each overload as having a unique name. `extern "C"` also can change the mechanism of passing arguments, and returning values.

Comment: So, in my case, if I included the header file in hello.cpp, the linkage specification would apply to the function declaration (I forgot that I don't have to use extern "C" on the function definition as well). Thus, the undecorated name called in main and defined in hello.cpp are the same and linking is successful.